# Issues with PayPal checkout in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does Any Body Knows That Why Is This Hapening because its not showing the content I want it to show. It supposed to show the order id, product price and quantity.

This is my coding.

```
        Response.Write("<form action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' name='buyCredits' id='buyCredits'>");
        Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>");
        Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='business' value='cccccc@yahoo.com'>");
        Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value'USD'>");
        Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value'payment for items'>");
        Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value'" + Id.ToString() + "'>");
        Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='amount' value'" + Session["total"].ToString() + "'>");
        Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='return' value'http://localhost:49584/payment_success.aspx?order=" + orderId.ToString() + "'>");
        Response.Write("</form>");

        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        Response.Write("document.getElementById('buyCredits').submit();");
        Response.Write("</script>");
```

Please check the image for results of the coding above.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a bunch of equals signs like;

```
value'USD'
```

should be

```
value='USD'
```

Also your return URL is localhost... This will only work locally and not when you deploy this.

Is there a reason you are directly writing this to the response? That is generally not a good idea (and certainly not idiomatic MVC, which you have tagged the question with so I presume you are using)...

Hopefully this is a learning project and not a real application as if you are dealing with real payments you should probably have more robust code...